# How to adjust row width according to data in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a scrollable JTable inside a JDialog and i wish to autoadjust the row width according to data length.

Any ideas?

Comment: _row width_? You either mean _row height_ or _column width_ and want to edit your question accordingly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the combination of [JTable.setRowHeight](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight%28int%29) method and a cell renderer based on [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

Comment: I don't see how this will help him auto-adjust the row ***width***. Have you fully read his question?

Comment: My bad :) For some reason I understood it as height. It is still possible that he actually meant height, so I'll leave the answer in place until he clears it up for us

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is being rendered and if you know the number if pixels...

Changing the column widths will be effected by the column auto resize policy.

If you want to set the pixel width...

```
int columnIndex = //... the index of the column
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tableColumn = columnModel.getColumn(columnIndex);
tableColumn.setWidth(pixelWidth);
```

If the column is rendering text and you know the number of characters that the column will display you can get the font metrics for the renderer/table...

```
// If you're using a cell renderer, you will need to get the cell renderer
// to get th font metrics
FontMerics fm = table.getFontMetrics(table.getFont());
int pixelWidth = fm.stringWidth("M") * characterCount;
```

If you're not using a text based renderer, you can use the renderer to gain some idea of the width...

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(0, columnIndex);
// You can also use table.getDefaultRenderer(Class)
Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                                  prototypeValue, // Some value the best represents the average value
                                  false,
                                  false,
                                  0,
                                  columnIndex);
int width = component.getPreferredWidth().width;
```

Comment: -1 for the fontMetrics .. that's something you _never_ (modulo the usual very odd corner case ;-) want nor need to do: simply query the prepared renderer for its pref.